# How to free properly a IntPtr pointing to a unmanaged array?

Tags: c#, marshalling, intptr, unmanaged-memory

I allocate IntPtr pointing to an array of struct to be used with unmanaged code. I found lot of resources on this subject and here is my final method (seems to work well):

```
public IntPtr ArrayToPtr<T>(T[] array)
{
    int size = array.Length;
    int elemSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));

    IntPtr result = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(elemSize * size);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        IntPtr ptr = new IntPtr(result.ToInt64() + elemSize * i);
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(array[i], ptr, false);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Now my questions:

- How to free properly this resulted IntPtr pointer ? (Is a FreeHGlobal(pointer) is enough ?)
- Is there any precaution to take if I use x86 or x64 system/application platform ?

Same questions for an array of strings (a char** in C):

```
public IntPtr ArrayOfStringToPtr(string[] array)
{
    int size = array.Length;
    int elemSize = IntPtr.Size;

    IntPtr result = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(elemSize * size);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        IntPtr strPtr = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(array[i]);
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(strPtr, new IntPtr(result.ToInt64() + elemSize * i), false);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you only need to call `Marshal.FreeHGlobal(hglobal)` once you have finished using the memory.

Because you are using `IntPtr` it will automatically work on x86 *or* x64 platforms because `IntPtr` takes care of the difference in pointer size for you.

However, you shouldn't use `ToInt64()` to do your pointer arithmetic.

Instead of

```
IntPtr ptr = new IntPtr(result.ToInt64() + elemSize * i);
```

Do this:

```
 IntPtr ptr = IntPtr.Add(result, elemSize * i);
```

Comment: Thx. What about the string array ?

Comment: The string array is using memory from `AllocHGlobal()` which is called from `StringToHGlobalAnsi()` so the same applies - just call `FreeHGlobal()` on the IntPtr returned from `StringToHGlobalAnsi()` to free the memory. Also remember to use `IntPtr.Add()` to do pointer arithmetic for the string example too.

Comment: Do you mean I just need to free the strPtr and not the result pointer  with FreeHGlobal ?

Comment: @EricDavid No I mean you have to free both using FreeHGlobal.